# Jänich Linear Algebra, Exercise 8.1*

Tags: linear-algebra

For $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n,n\ge 2$, define $|x|:=\max_i|x_i|$. Show that there exists no inner  product $\langle,\rangle$ on $\mathbb R^n$, for which $\langle x,x\rangle=|x|^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Please note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could answer any of the following. What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried so far? Are you aware of the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces)?

Comment: Just affirming the previous comment, one way of handling this would be to look at properties of norms induced by inner products and showing that one or more of them fail for your norm.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks. I get it.